# Maven plugin for Eclipse Juno -> can't find conf directory under .m2

Tags: maven, tomcat, m2eclipse

I am new to Maven plugin. I have downloaded latest eclipse juno and Maven plugin from eclipse MarketPlace.
I can see .m2 directory under C:\Documents and Settings\usernam.m2

I want to configure maven plugin to deploy .war files to tomcat.
I couldn't find conf/settings.xml under any Maven featrues/plugins or .m2 directory.

Do I need to download Maven manually and then configure eclipse to use those files?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a blog about [How To Deploy Maven Based War File To Tomcat](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-deploy-maven-based-war-file-to-tomcat/) by [Mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/author/mkyong/).

By Overview we need to use the [tomcat-maven-plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin.html)

#### The Tomcat version 6

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
               ...
            </configuration>
    </plugin>
</build>
```

#### The Tomcat version 7

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
               ...
            </configuration>
    </plugin>
</build>
```

Not only, But also need to install the Tomcat to our machine as well.

I hope this may help.

Comment: Charlee, I am following same blog. According to that blog, there are some changes in maven/config/settings.xml. I couldn't find config folder or settings.xml under .m2 repository. So my doubt is, I may need to download maven and then use it as external configuration in eclipse

Comment: Hi, you will see how to create the settings.xml at http://maven.apache.org/settings.html